# nested loops and IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python

I am trying to create a script that does the following:

**STEP 1:** Read row 1 from listofscenarios.txt. (i.e., the row reads as a 100_100 string).

**STEP 2:** According to that string name, open the file with the corresponding name (i.e., 100_100.txt)

**STEP 3:** Copy row 1 from 100_100.txt and paste it at row 1 at final.txt (this file will have all the results from all iterations).

**STEP 4:** Start at STEP 1 and do the same but now reading the next row (i.e., row 2.) Take the string name as before (i.e., 80_80), open the corresponding file, copy line 2, and  paste it to the final.txt at row 2.

Until now I have done the following but it doesn't work:
a) I get this error message although the file is there: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '100_100\n.txt'. I couldn't troubleshoot that based on similar postings
b) Besides error (a) I think the nested loops are not working as intended.

```
with open('listofscenarios.txt',"r") as fp: 
for scenario in iter(fp.readline, ''): 
    with open("%s.txt" %scenario, "r") as f1:
        for line in iter(f1.readline, ''):
            reading = f1.readline()
            with open("final.txt", "w+") as f2:
                for row in iter(f2.readline, ''):
                    writing = f1.writelines(reading)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole solution may look like this, ignoring how Pythonic it is:

```
fpl =  open("final.txt", "w")
with open('listofscenarios.txt',"r") as fp: 
    for i, scenario in enumerate(iter(fp.readline, '')):
        scenario = scenario.split('\n')[0]
        with open("%s.txt" %scenario, "r") as f1:
            fpl.write(f1.readlines()[i])
fpl.close()
```